# How should I connect these objects in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a Book class in an Angular6 project:

```
export class Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
}
```

I have a library component which lists all my book objects, and a book-details component which lists details of an individual book. I'm trying to create an author-works component that will list all the books of a particular author by selecting an author hyperlink in the library component.

Back to my question. Should I create a new class, Author:

```
export class Author {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

that injects its ID as a foreign key into my Book object (so I can use this ID to list all books corresponding to a particular author) like I would in something like SQL? I'm new to Angular and unsure what common/best practices are.

So it would end up something like this:

```
export class Book {
    id: number;
    authorId: number;
    title: string;
}
```

Comment: *like I would in something like SQL*...are you planning on communicating with a backend database? If so, I'd start there with database design. IMO Books and Authors is a many-to-many relationship so would have association table BookAuthor which has ids of Book and Author

Comment: This is a mock project I've started to help me learn Angular, I won't be communicating with a backend database (although I am using an in-memory web api to simulate a data server). I'm treating it as a one-to-many relationship for the sake of simplicity (one author to many books). If I feel like expanding it later I'll probably do as you suggested. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would've add an `authorId` property to `Book` class, and then for the array of books you can filter by the selected author by doing something like:

```
this.books.filter(book => book.authorId === this.selectedAuthorId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add Author to the book as a separate class. But ultimately this would come down to the question of how much information for an author you would want to be available under an Instance of Book. This way you have access to all the information under `book.author` for the author (name, age etc etc) however if you don't need the authors information or you already have it beforehand you could just save `author_id`.

**Book Class**

```
export class Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: Author;
}
```

**Author Class**

```
export class Author {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Then you can filter your array of books by the `author.id` value to get all books by an author

Comment: I think I'll go with this suggestion, thanks! I didn't think to add Author into Book as a whole object rather than just take its id as a foreign key. This seems the simplest way whilst still keeping my code clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to make 2 interfaces, for example :

**model-author.ts**

```
export interface ModelAuthor {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**model-book.ts**

```
import { ModelAuthor } from './model-author'; 

export interface ModelBook {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: ModelAuthor;
}
```

**book.component.ts**

```
import { ModelBook } from '....'; // path regarding your folder tree

export class Book {
  books: ModelBook[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Harry Potter',
      author: { id: 0, name: 'JK.Rowling' }
    }
  ];
}
```